# Proof for square root series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

$$\sum_{i=1}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2i-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2i+1}}= 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x+1}}$$
I need to prove that the sums from the LHS are equal or at least equal to the terms from the RHS.

Is that possible?

I tried to solve it but I made some mistakes.

[image]

To be honest I have no idea if this is wrong or correct.

What are your suggestions?

Comment: Do you not see that the inner terms cancel with each other?

Comment: @PeterForeman I do,but the question was if my solution is correct.You didn't answered.I didn't analysed my answer deeper so I have no clue.That is what I need from you.

Comment: Are there mistakes in my series?If so,which one of them?

Comment: The result is correct but you should have written $$\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1}}-\frac1{\sqrt{3}}\right)+\left(\frac1{\sqrt{3}}-\frac1{\sqrt{5}}\right)+\dots+\left(\frac1{\sqrt{2x-3}}-\frac1{\sqrt{2x-1}}\right)+\left(\frac1{\sqrt{2x-1}}-\frac1{\sqrt{2x+1}}\right)=1-\frac1{\sqrt{2x+1}}$$

Comment: The LHS converges [conditionally][1] to the RHS. 

  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_convergence

Answer (score 1):

It is in fact the [Telescopic Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i-a_{i-1}=(a_1-a_0)+(a_2-a_1)+(a_3-a_2)+\cdots+(a_n-a_{n-1})=a_n-a_0$$